# BoxLayout: can't setup child component size

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, boxlayout

I have a `JFrame` - `SuperTest` and `JPanel` - `SuperLogin`. The login panel has the username and password input fields and a login button. I want it to look like this:

[image]

but it looks like the pic below, with input fields having too huge height and width.

**SuperTest.java**:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class SuperTest extends JFrame {
    public SuperTest()  {
        add(new SuperLogin());
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(600, 400);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SuperTest test = new SuperTest();
    }
}
```

**SuperLogin.java**:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class SuperLogin extends JPanel {
    private JButton loginButton =
            new JButton("Login");
    private TextField usernameField =
            new TextField();
    private TextField passwordField =
            new TextField();

    public SuperLogin()  {
        BoxLayout layout =
                new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
        setLayout(layout);

        add(new JLabel("Login"));

        add(usernameField);
        add(passwordField);
        add(loginButton);

        componentSetup();
    }

    private void componentSetup()  {
        loginButton.setSize(20, 10);
        usernameField.setSize(100, 50);
        passwordField.setSize(100, 50);

        loginButton.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(20, 10));
        usernameField.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(100, 50));
        passwordField.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(100, 50));

        loginButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(20, 10));
        usernameField.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 50));
        passwordField.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 50));

    }
}
```

I read that setting min, preferred size would be enough, but it looks like it's not.

[image]

Comment: Don't play with minimum and preferred size. Each component should be responsible for determining its own size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put everything into a single class. Explanations after the code.

```java
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class SuperOne implements Runnable {
    private JButton  loginButton;
    private JFrame  frame;
    private JPasswordField  passwordField;
    private JTextField  usernameField;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        showGui();
    }

    private JPanel createLoginPanel() {
        JPanel loginPanel = new JPanel();
        BoxLayout layout = new BoxLayout(loginPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS);
        loginPanel.setLayout(layout);
        loginPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));
        JLabel loginLabel = new JLabel("Login");
        loginLabel.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        usernameField = new JTextField(10);
        usernameField.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        passwordField = new JPasswordField(10);
        passwordField.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        loginButton = new JButton("login");
        loginButton.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        loginPanel.add(loginLabel);
        loginPanel.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(15));
        loginPanel.add(usernameField);
        loginPanel.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(5));
        loginPanel.add(passwordField);
        loginPanel.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(5));
        loginPanel.add(loginButton);
        return loginPanel;
    }

    private void showGui() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(createLoginPanel());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    /**
     * Start here.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new SuperOne());
    }
}
```

1. All code that deals with the GUI components must run on the *Event Dispatch Thread* (EDT). Although not mandatory, I like to explicitly launch the EDT by calling `EventQueue.invokeLater()`.
2. Refer to the Web page with the tutorial on `BoxLayout` that appears in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63159903/boxlayout-cant-setup-child-component-size/63160300#63160300).
3. `JTextField` and `JPasswordField` both have a *columns* property. I find that better for setting a desired width than using `setPreferredSize()`

Here is a screen capture of the running app.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Works perfectly. I realized, however, that I need the `username` and `password` labels too. I managed to add them by uniting the labels and textfields in the extra nested `JPanel`s, but couldn't get it to work with just adding it alongside the textfields. Would it require two `BoxLayout`, side by side, maybe?

Comment: @parsecer *I need the username and password labels too.* - use a `GridBagLayout` for all the components.

Comment: @parsecer I answered the question you asked. It appears you want a different GUI to the one you described in your question. Perhaps you should post a new question? Alternatively, maybe this Q&A will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62964489/how-to-make-my-user-interface-self-adapt-to-the-show-and-hide-of-jpanel/62964801#62964801

Answer (score 0):

From the [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) for BoxLayout:

> What if none of the components has a maximum width? In this case, if all the components have identical X alignment, then all components are made as wide as their container.

So you just need to set the maximum size.